# How to navigate to a path that is not declared in App.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has a list of cars, and I am trying to navigate to a new page with the id of the car, for instance:

`localhost:4000/cars/1223` and it will navigate to the new page. The only way that i know how to do this is register the route in the `<Route />` and then to use `<NavLink />` to navigate to that page, but I cannot register all the possible routes at App.js, so it must be a better way to do this. Also I am aware that i have to send the Id of the car so I can fetch the details of that car.

```html
// App.js
<Container>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={CarList} />
    <Route exact path="/cars" component={CarList} />
    <Route exact path="/cars/:carId" />
  </Switch>
</Container>;
```

And the component is:

```js
class CarItem extends React.Component {
  navigateToCarPage = () => {
    // here should navigate to car page
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { make, carPrice } = this.props;
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.navigateToCarPage()}>
        <div className="col">
          <h3>{make}</h3>
          <p>Price: {carPrice}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CarItem;
```

Comment: Assuming `NavLink` is some sort of a wrapper over react-router's `Link`, you can probably use the [object variation of the `to` prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object) and send any dynamic variables as query parameters to a static route if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem, but using `NavLink` this way should do it:

```
class CarItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { make, carPrice, carId } = this.props;
    return (
    <NavLink to={`/cars/${carId}`}>
      <div>
        <div className="col">
          <h3>{make}</h3>
          <p>Price: {carPrice}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
    );
  }
}
export default CarItem;
```

Assuming you have `carId` from your props.

Comment: Can I pass any props to the NavLink?

Comment: What is NavLink ? Is it from react router? (which version) You should only pass a `to` prop to NavLink: `to={`/cars/${carId}`}`